# crop UIImage function not work properly when photo take from camera.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, crop

[image: Image that are taken using camera and set in square box . i want this bottle image from top to bottom]I used crop function that crop image . It is work good when i take photo from photo library but when i use camera to take picture and crop the image. the crop function give me a wrong crop image .

My crop logic:

```
float zoomScale = 1.0 / [scrollView zoomScale];

CGRect rect;
rect.origin.x = [scrollView contentOffset].x * zoomScale;
rect.origin.y = [scrollView contentOffset].y * zoomScale;
rect.size.width = [scrollView bounds].size.width * zoomScale;
rect.size.height = [scrollView bounds].size.height * zoomScale;



UIImage *cropped = [self cropImage:imageView.image toRect:rect];//[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];

//CGImageRelease(cr);

return cropped;


static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}

-(UIImage*)cropImage:(UIImage*)originalImage toRect:(CGRect)rect{

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect);

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);
CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

if (originalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -rect.size.height);

} else if (originalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -rect.size.width, 0);

} else if (originalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    // NOTHING
} else if (originalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));
}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

UIImage *resultImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return resultImage;
}
```

what is the problem with my code ?
image taken from camera is not proper crop .
Please solve it .

I want whole bottle image see in first image that i have to set but when i press crop button and give me a wrong image . seein second image.

[image: But After crop the image crop something wrong.]

Comment: Define "wrong crop image".

Comment: @Larme i add two image .

Comment: Try to look at the value of `rect` and `originalImageSize`. The crop seems to work, but the size seems wrong. Maybe an issue with the `zoomScale`.